# Connection string for connecting mongo database with SSL enabled

Tags: mongodb, encryption, ssl

Am facing some below problem in my mongodb replication environment

I have 3 replica set environment with SSL enabled and ssl mode as preferSSL

3 servers has 3 different Key file with common CA file

when i try to connect the mongo shell with below command it works fine

mongo --ssl --host hostname:port --sslPEMKeyFile "/home/mongod/keyfile.pem" --sslCAFile /home/mongod/CAfile.pem

My question is how to provide these details in connection string to connect the database from application perspective

MongoDB version: 4.0.2
OS: Amazon Linux

Thanks,
Vignesh

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which driver you are using.
https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/driver-connection/#driver-examples

Comment: Our application team is using mongoose client for connecting mongodb and node.js with version 5.3.7, mongodb they are using 3.1.8